# Usando 'groupby' em um dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

Tenho um dataframe com 60 colunas, mas para o caso preciso de somente 3

```
    ID          DT_DATE     NR_PRICE
0   22828949    2019-02-26  453.00
1   22828949    2019-02-22  453.00
2   22828949    2019-02-18  453.00
3   22828949    2019-02-05  453.00
4   22828950    2019-02-26  189.00
5   22828950    2019-02-24  189.00
6   22828950    2019-02-19  189.00
7   22828950    2019-02-14  189.00
8   22828950    2019-02-01  411.05
```

Preciso listar a 1ª data, penúltima e última data com seus respectivos valores
Tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
def custom(series):
    min_date = list(series)[0]
    pen_date = list(series)[-2]
    max_date = list(series)[-1]

    return min_date,pen_date,max_date
```

---

```
def get_price(series):
    price_a = list(series)[0]
    price_c = list(series)[-2]
    price_b = list(series)[-1]

    return price_a,price_c,price_b
```

---

```
dfb=df.groupby(["ID"],as_index=False).agg({"DT_DATE":custom,"NR_PRICE":get_price})
```

Qdo eu executo o mesmo, aparece a seguinte msg de erro

```
"IndexError: list index out of range"
```

Alguém ja passou por isso?

Answer (score 0):

Para esse problema eu não usaria o `groupby`, veja minha solução:

Criei um exemplo em que a partir dos dados que vc colocou na questão (peguei apenas 6 linhas deles) crio um `DataFrame`(`df0`) fazendo sort na coluna de datas, copio o conteúdo para um segundo, eliminando as linhas com datas repetidas (`df1`) e, finalmente crio um terceiro (`df2`) somente com o que vc pede (primeira, penultima e ultima data).

```
import pandas as pd

dados = [['22828949', '2019-02-26', '453.00'],
 ['22828949', '2019-02-22', '453.00'],
 ['22828949', '2019-02-18', '453.00'],
 ['22828949', '2019-02-05', '453.00'],
 ['22828950', '2019-02-26', '189.00'],
 ['22828950', '2019-02-24', '189.00']]

# Construindo o dataframe (Note o sort na colua de datas)
df0 = pd.DataFrame(dados, columns=['ID', 'DT_DATE', 'NR_PRICE']).sort_values(by=['DT_DATE'])

# Removendo as datas duplicatas
df1 = df0.drop_duplicates(subset='DT_DATE', keep='last')

# Extraindo o primeiro, o último e o penultimo registros
df2 = df1.head(1).append(df1.tail(2))

# Apresentando o resultado
print(df2)
```

Saída:

```
         ID     DT_DATE NR_PRICE
3  22828949  2019-02-05   453.00
5  22828950  2019-02-24   189.00
4  22828950  2019-02-26   189.00
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/pandas-head-tail)